# Como realiza atribuição de dados a uma struct lendo de um arquivo CSV?

Tags: c, struct, csv

Estou com dificuldade de atribui valores lidos de um arquivo no formato csv ao uma struct, meu arquivo tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
1;República Checa;156.9
2;Irlanda;131.1
3;Alemanha;115.8
4;Austrália;109.9
5;Áustria;108.3
```

e meu código esta assim:

```
struct Nodo{
      int classificacao;
      char pais[30];
      float consumo;
};
```

função que realiza a leitura do arquivo csv:

```
void leArquivoDeDados() {
 int length;
 char * buffer;

 struct Nodo nodo[35];

 ifstream is;
 is.open ("dados.csv", ios::in);

 is.seekg (0, ios::end);
 length = is.tellg();
 is.seekg (0, ios::beg);

 if (is.is_open())
 {
    int n = 0;
    buffer = new char[length];
    is.read(buffer,length);

   if (length > 0)
   {
      while(n < length) //isso substitue o ";" para um espaço
      {
         n++;
         if (buffer[n] == ';') buffer[n] = '\t';
      }

      printf("%s", buffer);
      getch();
      delete []buffer;
   }
 }
 else {
   printf("Arquivo não foi aberto");
   getch();
}

  is.close();
}
```

Estou declarando minha Struct como um vetor de 35 posições e pretendo atribuir os valores antes de cada ponto e virgula, por exemplo:

```
Nodo.classificacao = 1;
Nodo.pais = 'Irlanda';
Nodo.consumo = 156.9;
```

Minha função esta conseguindo escrever no terminal o meu arquivo, mas eu não sei como realizar essa atribuição no exemplo acima no tempo da leitura do arquivo, estou substituindo o ";" por espaços só para visualizar melhor no terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que o melhor comando para coletar dados de arquivos e jogar direto em variáveis é o `fscanf`, post é possível determinar o formato de entrada.

O arquivo foi aberto com o `fopen`, acho que usando o `ifstream` não terá o mesmo efeito.

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt","r");

int x;
for(x=0;x<35/*tamanho do vetor*/;x++){
    /* %d - lê um inteiro
       %30[^;] - lê os bytes até o caractere ';'
       %f - lê um float
    */
    fscanf(f,"%d;%30[^;];%f\n", &nodo[x].classificacao, nodo[x].pais, &nodo[x].consumo); // lê os dados e armazena em nodo
    printf("%d - %s - %f\n", n[x].classificacao, n[x].pais, n[x].consumo);
}
```

Comment: @JJoao. Realmente pensei em colocar "lê os caracteres", mas o comando deverá fazer a leitura de tudo que estiver antes do ";" independente do que esteja lá, por isso que estou usando o termo "bytes" ao inver de "caracteres".